# Google Chrome extension to play music

Tags: chrome, music

I am searching for an Chrome extension by which I can play music saved in my local drive.

All I want is to play music from my computer without using any media player, but by using my browser only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enjoy Music Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enjoy-music-player/hncfgilfeieogcpghjnnhddghgdjbekl) (this one also supports online music) or [Achshar Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/achshar-player/fddboknafkepdchidokknkeidnaejnkh?hl=en-US) seem to do exactly what you want: play local music with Chrome, though I have not tested them myself. They also come with a neat music-browser, playlists and some more *media player-features*. They run offline in a separate window (**Chrome App**), so you don't even need to open Chrome itself.

If you don't want that, there's also [MP3 Player by AntiMatter](http://antimatter15.com/player/player.html) which runs online and supports searching for songs by name or artist and shuffling.

Visit [this post on addictivetips.com](http://www.addictivetips.com/web/use-google-chrome-as-a-music-player-for-local-files/) to learn about a more powerful 
Chrome App called [Remo Music Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remo-music-player/ajilpdcmebalpffmjjopcingplogifhb) and a more simple version of that called [MP3 Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mp3-player/kbiheleggoempookkoblhdgmlojbicob).